# Android camera, how to set default format?

Tags: android, camera

I want to capture image and upload to server from android client. The supported formats are jpeg,jpg and png. I am not making a custom camera in my application and am calling the camera using below code snippet:-

```
 Intent intent  = new Intent();

 intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);

 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

My doubts :-

1. Is there any guaranteed format(s) in which the native camera captures the picture?
2. Is there any way to command the camera to take image in a particular format?

(NB:- I know that I can achieve this by making a custom camera, but I dont want to do that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any guaranteed format(s) in which the native camera captures the picture?

No. Usually, it will be JPEG, as that is all that many camera apps know about. Possibly, the camera app might examine the MIME type associated with your `Uri` (e.g., via file extension) and do something based upon that.

But, please understand that there are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models. Those devices ship with hundreds of different pre-installed camera apps, and users can install others from the Play Store and elsewhere. The behavior of camera apps will vary widely, including having bugs.

> Is there any way to command the camera to take image in a particular format?

No.